# Почему хелпер "devise_controller?" возвращает false для моего кода?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Почему хелпер `devise_controller?` возвращает `false` для следующего кода:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
layout :resource
protected
def resource
  if devise_controller?
    #"admin"
    puts "admin"
  else
    #"application"
    puts "app"
  end
end
end
```

при этом в строке браузера переход на "http://127.0.0.1:3000/admin/review"

файл routes.rb:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'admin/show'
  get 'admin/upload'
  get 'admin/review'
  get 'welcome/index'
  get 'welcome/portfolio'
  get 'welcome/about'
  get 'welcome/contact'
  get 'welcome/blog'
  get 'welcome/review'
 end
```

при этом для остальных маршрутов   get 'admin/show'и get 'admin/upload' хелпер выдает true ....

**Обновление**

В общем проблему решил так. Добавил в `ApplicationController` фильтр

```
before_filter :my_filter, unless: :devise_controller?

 def my_filter
    if params['controller'] == 'admin'
      render layout: "admin"
    end
 end
```

Но вопрос по существу остается - почему через `layout` тоже самое со сбоями работает?

Comment: Добавьте код Admin контроллера

Answer (score 1):

Метод `devise_controller?` лишь проверяет унаследован ли ваш класс от класса `DeviseController`

```
def devise_controller?
   is_a?(::DeviseController)
end
```

У вас контроллер наследуется от `ActionController::Base`, поэтому условие не всегда может быть выполнено. Для проверки факта аутентификации лучше воспользоваться хелперами Devise: `user_signed_in?` и `current_user`. Если вам нужно сменить layout не зависимо от того, аутентифицирован пользователь или нет - просто меняйте его в render (как вы собственно и поступили в Обновлении).